# CPU maxed at 20% usage but Windows shows 100% CPU usage

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

RealTemp shows that my CPU usage never goes above 25%, while Windows Task Manager thinks it's using 100%.

The temperatures of the CPU never goes above 30 degrees on core 1 and 2, and never goes above 22 degrees on core 3 and 4, even while playing intensive games or other CPU intensive things. My specs:

- i5-6600K, liquid cooled
- GTX 1080 Ti
- 16 GB DDR4 2133 MHz

I've updated drivers and bios but no difference

Any ideas?

https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/23961204

HWiNFO:

[image: HWiNFO]

Comment: Real Temp and Task Manager show the same values on my machine.  (a) have you restarted recently?  (b) might the liquid cooling have an impact

Comment: Yes, I restart once every day. The temperatures are completely fine

Comment: Do you have a power profile which is limiting max CPU to 20%?

Comment: I've set it to High Performance and minimum/maximum CPU usage to 100% in the power profile

Comment: It sounds similar to issues experienced here https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/task-manager-always-showing-100-cpu.3278671/ and https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/a-confused-cpu-and-system-fan.2893340/. I see you've already set your power profile to the highest but try resetting the profile to default settings.